# How to replace Plus.PeopleApi in the new play-services-auth:8.3.0 and google-services:1.5.0-beta2?

Tags: java, android, mobile, google-api

i'm having some issues regarding this topic. I want to get the gender of the person that log-in into my Android app using Google Plus account, but every example i have found, use something like this :

```
if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {

        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();         

        try {
            int genderInt = currentPerson.getGender();
         String   gender     = String.valueOf(genderInt);
        String birthday = currentPerson.getBirthday();

        System.out.println("gender" + gender + "bod" + birthday);

        } 


        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

        String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
    }
```

They use the Plus.PeopleApi that does not exist anymore in the new play-services-auth:8.3.0 and google-services:1.5.0-beta2. I want to know how the new API replace this, or which is the new way to retrieve the Gender and other profile data, such as the birthdate.

Thank you.